# How can I allow multiple long-press gestures simultaneously on an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, gesture, multi-touch

I currently have a few drag-and-drop'able layers linked to UILabels. I have a LongPressRecognizer picking up long-presses on the labels, and moving the layers with the labels being dragged around.

I've implemented this by catching gestures in the recognizer's target like such:

```
- (void)handleDragging:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    switch ([gestureRecognizer state]) 
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            [self startDragging:gestureRecognizer];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            [self doDrag:gestureRecognizer];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            [self stopDragging:gestureRecognizer];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to enable a user to, while they are dragging one label, have the ability to perform an additional long-press on another label to drag multiple labels simultaneously. As the recognizer currently accepts 1 touch (numberOfTouchesRequired = 1), it doesn't seem to be able to pick up additional events. However, the gestureRecognizerStateChanged event is fired every time another touch event occurs on the iPad. numberOfTouches on the recognizer still shows a single touch, however.

Is giving each label its own LongPressRecognizer the best solution, or is there something more elegant I can do with a single recognizer?

Answer (score 6):

In your view controller...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {        
    return YES;
}
```

And don't forget to

```
recognizer.delegate = self;
```

when creating each gesture...

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow for a single long-press recognizer to manage multiple long-presses.

I guess that's what I'm really asking. Now that I think about it in that way, I'm not even sure that's how recognizers are supposed to work? Are they simply a handler for one gesture at a time?